# See why my file is marked dirty

Tags: vim

At some point I made some changes to my vimrc and/or plugins and only a while later I noticed that sometimes when I open a file for editing, it is immediately marked as dirty. I try hitting `u` to undo, but it tells me `"Already at oldest change"`.

Is there a way I can get a list of what changes have been made *since the last save*, i.e., the changes that are marking the file as dirty? I tried `:changes` but it's showing me all the latest changes, even those that occurred the last time I edited the file (i.e., before saving closing, and editing again) with no indication of when it was last saved.

Comment: Something like [gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/)?

Comment: @evanbas - Probably in general, but unfortunately not in this case: it just shows an empty undo tree, despite the file being marked dirty. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm try seeing if `:h :DiffOrig` tells you anything.

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks, another good idea that unfortunately didn't work for me: the diff shows nothing has changed.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm check for autocmds related to the filetype of it appears to be related to the file. Other than that I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buffer is marked as *modified*, there's nothing in the undo list, *and* you have a working undo, it's that either

- a plugin has explicitly `:setlocal modified`
- your undo history got cleared (via `:set undolevels=-1` and restoring the original value)

With the mentioned `:h :DiffOrig`, you can check whether there have been actual changes vs. the persisted file.